# Bot asks for clarification even on static buttons

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using BotFramework FormFlow. One of the questions gives a static list of choices that the user can choose from. When the user chooses Central Us for instance it still asks for clarification, is there a way to avoid that since it's clear what the user chose.
[image]

Here's the code:

```
        [Prompt("Please choose the region in which the cluster should be created {||}")]
    public RegionOptions? DesiredGeoRegion;


    public enum RegionOptions
   {
    AustraliaEast,
    AustraliaSoutheast,
    BrazilSouth,
    CanadaCentral,
    CanadaEast,
    CentralIndia,
    CentralUS,
    EastAsia,
    EastUS,
    EastUS2,
    JapanEast,
    JapanWest,
    NorthCentralUS,
    NorthEurope,
    SouthCentralUS,
    SouthIndia,
    SoutheastAsia,
    UKNorth,
    UKSouth2,
    WestCentralUS,
    WestEurope,
    WestIndia,
    WestUS,
    WestUS2
   }
```

Comment: Can you post the Enum code?

Comment: Sure, I've just added the Enum code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation, this is the expected behavior since `FormFlow` will try to disambiguate when the term entered is also found in any of the other options. In this case Central US is part of the other options displayed in the second message.

[image]

A way to overcome this is using the [Terms attribute](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d2/d27/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_form_flow_1_1_terms_attribute.html) to override the default terms used to match the enum value to the user input. I tried this and it worked as expected:

```
public enum RegionOptions
{
    AustraliaEast,
    AustraliaSoutheast,
    BrazilSouth,
    CanadaCentral,
    CanadaEast,
    CentralIndia,
    CentralUS,
    EastAsia,
    EastUS,
    EastUS2,
    JapanEast,
    JapanWest,
    [Terms("North Central US")]
    NorthCentralUS,
    NorthEurope,
    [Terms("South Central US")]
    SouthCentralUS,
    SouthIndia,
    SoutheastAsia,
    UKNorth,
    UKSouth2,
    [Terms("West Central US")]
    WestCentralUS,
    WestEurope,
    WestIndia,
    WestUS,
    WestUS2
}
```

Note that you will see the same issues with the EastUS and WestUS options.